# Is it possible to use Azure Mobile App and Azure AD B2C to authenticate localhost web?

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-ad-b2c

I know that local debugging using tokens is possible using http://www.systemsabuse.com/2015/12/04/local-debugging-with-user-authentication-of-an-azure-mobile-app-service/. Would it be possible to go to thesite.com/.auth/login/aad and login and use that cookie for localhost (for testing the web app - not the mobile app)?

I am currently using the .auth/login/aad cookie to authenticate Nancy. I do by generating a ZumoUser out of the Principal.

```
        Before.AddItemToEndOfPipeline(UserToViewBag);
```

and

```
    internal static async Task<Response> UserToViewBag(NancyContext context, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        var principal = context.GetPrincipal();

        var zumoUser = await ZumoUser.CreateAsync(context.GetPrincipal());

        context.ViewBag.User = zumoUser;
        context.Items["zumoUser"] = zumoUser;

        var url = context.Request.Url;
        if (zumoUser.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            _logger.DebugFormat("{0} requested {1}", zumoUser, url.Path);
        }
        else
        {
            _logger.DebugFormat("{0} requested {1}", "Anonymous", url.Path);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Please feel free to let me know if still have the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You need to read "the book" as it is a complex subject.  The book is available open source at http://aka.ms/zumobook and the content you want is in Chapter 2.

Comment: I went through Chapter 2 but I think it principally deals with using the zumo token to authenticate from the mobile app side. When I go to .auth/login/aad and return (from a browser), it seems that my whole site is already authenticated with the aad credentials. That is what I'm looking to apply to my localhost.

Comment: So, you didn't read the bit about using AlternateLoginHost in the mobile apps client to go off to App Service for the auth, but then continue using localhost?

Comment: I did. And I know how to do that. I'm not talking about mobile app login, but directly going to the website. I want to leverage the Zumo auth for not just the mobile but also for the web app side. Currently I use .auth/login/aad and am able to authenticate to Nancy. But I would like to use that cookie auth or a cookie auth for the localhost debugging as well.

Comment: I don't think that's possible today.

Answer (score 0):

> Would it be possible to go to thesite.com/.auth/login/aad and login and use that cookie for localhost (for testing the web app - not the mobile app)?

No, this is impossible. The JWT token verification is based on the stand protocol(OpenId connect or Oauth 2) we can follow. But there is no official document or SDK about the the cookie issued by the [Easy Auth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview) verification.

Comment: Is there a way I can read the AD B2C cookie or make it valid for my site using Azure?

Comment: The cookies is only readable from the  host of the HTML document in which the <script> is embedded. So it is not able to read the AD B2C cookie from your site. And most of cookies is only read from server( HTTP only) for security consideration. More detail about cookies you may refer this [document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie).